# Как обновить диалог на websocket?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, workerman

Пишу чат на сокетах. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при открытом диалоге не выводятся новые сообщения, требуется закрыть диалог и заново открыть.
Отправляю сообщение так: при отправке с сервера в `onMessage` задается `action = 'send'`, в браузере проверяется, что `action == 'send'`.
Используется библиотека *Workerman*.

Возможно ли использовать один `onMessage` или нужно искать другое решение?

Comment: А вы как принимаете новые сообщения?

Comment: Проверяю какой event приходит в `socket.onmessage = function(event){}`, исходя из него выполняю какие-то действия. На сервере пробрасываю разные event'ы через `$connection->send($data)`.